# Find the partial derivatives of a Lagrangian

Tags: calculus

$L = \ln(c)-\ln((1-p)s+n) + \lambda(p(1-t)wn-c) + \mu(ps-n)$

Find the partial derivative in respect to $c, n$, and $s$. This is what I have.

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial c} = 1/c - λ = 0$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial n} = 1/n + λ(p(1-t)w) - μ = 0$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial s} = 1/s - p/sp + μp = 0$

Is this correct?

Comment: I helped clean up the math formatting, please take a look at this for future reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Also, it will help if you give a little more info, for example, what is FOC?  I assume from the text that this is "first order condition," but what does that mean?  It may be possible that people who are unfamiliar may still be able to help if you provide a little extra info.